# Moving FileZilla stored connections to new computer

Tags: filezilla

Due to a recent computer issue I had to purchase a new computer. Fortunately I was able to install the old SSD drive in the new computer as a 2nd SSD device (D:). I installed FileZilla Client on the C: drive. So the questions...

Is there a folder/file on the D: drive that I can move to the C: drive so that all of the installed Connections and setting will be available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FileZilla saves stored sites to `%APPDATA%\FileZilla\sitemanager.xml`. That usually is path like:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\FileZilla\sitemanager.xml
```

Just copy that file over to your new machine.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a folder/file on the D: drive that I can move to the C: drive
> so that all of the installed Connections and setting will be
> available?

New computer with no prior preparations - normal situation, so no, you cannot use the old SSD to recreate your new PC with settings and connections.  You will have to do that manually. Again, quite normal.

You can try to get your old Windows User Profile from the old SSD. You would need to take ownership of it.

That will allow you to get documents and email, and possibly browser favorites as well as well as FileZilla connections. If you can see the old folder, look in C:\Users\username\AppData for applicable folder names.

But as noted, connections (network and folder sharing) and settings (user profile settings) will need to be set up manually.  Settings (app and Window settings are often (usually) stored in the registry. I am not sure but FileZilla connections are likely in the registry as well.